# What is the term/concept for the square brackets on this snippet of javascript?

Tags: javascript

What is the term/concept for the square brackets on this snippet of javascript?

```js
handleInputChange(event){
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked: target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }
```

Comment: It's called a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

Answer (score 4):

It's called a "Computed Property Name". You can find more info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).